# Are there any in-depth accounts on the history of the so-called 'city name statues' phenomenon?

Tags: names, cities, reference

A few years ago, Amsterdam had a big collection of statues consisting of letters that spelled '*I am*sterdam':

[image]

The letters were removed because a majority the city council associated them with excessive individualism.

Another, albeit less exorbitant, example of a city name statue can be found in Sitges, a coastal Spanish city:

[image]

**Question**: I was wondering whether there are any in-depth accounts on the history of such city name statues. I'd like to learn more about why they came about in different cities, which artists were involved, which city was the first to have such a collection of statues, and more.

Comment: Do mileposts count? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_milepost

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Many cities have some artwork with their name at railway stations and airports to welcome visitors. Here's a similar status in Edinburgh https://www.internationalairportreview.com/news/31147/edinburgh-airport-consulation-airspace-change-programme/ . I assume the problem in Amsterdam were the words 'I am', not the named of the city.

Comment: More frequently the name is written on a prominent building like the railway station hall of the airport terminal. At stations and at access roads there are also signs with the name, and many cities or even villages have some artwork on access roads. I'd have thought it's just a practical thing that every city wants to welcome visitors with something nice and also inform them where they are, which wasn't necessarily obvious to drivers and train travelers before smartphones and in-car GPS.